# Does a dynamic allocation of characters using new require for the compiler to initialize them to zero

Tags: c++, c++11

For example:

```
char *p=new char[100];
```

Must the character array pointed to by `p` be initialized to zeroes per the C++ standard? Or, is this behavior completely compiler dependant?

gcc seems to call the default constructor on each character, which of course initializes them to zero. Visual C++ 2010 does not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, POD types are left uninitialised when they are created by `new`. You could value-initialise them to zero if you want:

```
char * p = new char[100]();
                        ^^
```

This is specified by the standard:

> C++11, 5.3.4/15: If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is *default-initialized* (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.
>
> 8.5/6: To *default-initialize* an object of type T means:
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> — if T is an array type, **each element is *default-initialized***;
> — otherwise, **no initialization is performed**.

Your other observation:

> gcc seems to call the default constructor on each character

It shouldn't do - especially as `char` doesn't have a constructor. If you replace it with a type with a default constructor, then that *will* be called for each element.

I get the following disassembly, with no sign of any initialisation:

```
int main() {
    char * p = new char[100];
    return p[0];
}

00000000004005f4 <main>:
  # set up stack frame
  push   %rbp
  mov    %rsp,%rbp
  sub    $0x10,%rsp

  # call `operator new[]` with an argument of 100
  mov    $0x64,%edi
  callq  4004e0 <operator new[](unsigned long)@plt>

  # put the return value into %eax
  mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  movzbl (%rax),%eax
  movsbl %al,%eax

  # return
  leaveq 
  retq
```

Comment: Is there anywhere in the standard where it states this explicitly?

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: Indeed there is; I'll look it up in a minute.

Comment: I was going to shout "value initialisation of arrays is not allowed" (have to wonder why, but I can testify that trying to do it reliably breaks the build), but surprisingly default initialisation indeed is allowed. +1 for pointing out something that has bugged me many times, saving me an extra loop from now on.

Comment: @Damon: It wasn't allowed in C++98; it was one of the few new features of C++03.